# Can you make the function's name a string plus a variable on javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

I currently have a javascript function that acts on a table. When you click on a table cell in a table row all the other cells disappear and the clicked cell gets moved to the leftmost of the table row and there will be a slider opening up on the right side of the table cell. I want to make each table cell's slider unique so I'm just wondering if there's a way to make a function's name a string plus a variable. For example if the clicked cell has a id of cell1 can I do something like let id = the id of the table cell and when I'm doing the function for the slider I name it 'slider' + id?

js

```
function handleCellClick(clickedCell) {
  const row = clickedCell.parentElement;
  const cells = row.children;
  const display = cells[cells.length - 1].style.display ? '' : 'none';

  for (let i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    cells[i].style.display = display;
  }
  if (display) { 
    const newCell = clickedCell.cloneNode(true);
    newCell.style.display = '';
    newCell.colSpan = cells.length;
    row.insertBefore(newCell, row.firstChild);
    openSlider(newCell);
  } else {
    clickedCell.remove();
    closeSlider(clickedCell);
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<table id='TrendGames'>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td id="cell1">
                <img class='GameCover' src='.png' alt="cell1" />
                </td>
                <td id="cell2">
                <img class='GameCover' src='.png' alt="cell2" />
                </td>
                <td id="cell3">
                <img class='GameCover' src='.png' alt="cell3" />
                </td>
                <td id="cell4">
                <img class='GameCover' src='.png' alt="cell4" />
                </td>
            </tr>
       </tbody>
</table>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use an object whose keys are the names and values are the functions to call. Then use `object[name]()` to call the function.

Comment: But you shouldn't need unique functions. Use a single function that takes the slider as an argument.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean? I'm kind of confused.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using "this" as parameter for your function ?

HTML

```
<table id='TrendGames'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="cell1" onclick="handleCellClick(this)">
        <img class='GameCover' src='BD.png' alt="cell1" />
      </td>
      <td id="cell2" onclick="handleCellClick(this)">
        <img class='GameCover' src='BD.png' alt="cell2" />
      </td>
      <td id="cell3" onclick="handleCellClick(this)">
        <img class='GameCover' src='BD.png' alt="cell3" />
      </td>
      <td id="cell4" onclick="handleCellClick(this)">
        <img class='GameCover' src='BD.png' alt="cell4" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

SCRIPT

```
function handleCellClick(clickedCell) {
  console.log(clickedCell.id+" is clicked") // logs id of td element
  let myPics = document.getElementsByClassName('GameCover');
  for (const iterator of myPics) {
    iterator.style.display='none';
  }
  clickedCell.childNodes[1].style = "display :'block'";
  const newCell1 = clickedCell.cloneNode(true);
  const newCell2 = clickedCell.cloneNode(true);
  newCell1.id=`firstcol_${clickedCell.id}`;
  newCell2.id=`secondcol_${clickedCell.id}`;
  const myTR = document.createElement("tr");
  clickedCell.childNodes[1].remove()
  myTR.appendChild(newCell1)
  myTR.appendChild(newCell2)
  clickedCell.appendChild(myTR);
}
```

I did not understand the logic entirely but using "this" as parameter you can use same function for different elements.

And yes you can change cloned nodes id whatever you like.

Comment: What about the reverse action though? Like when you click on the element again when the action already happened it reverses it and returns it to the normal state.

Comment: What i did was create new row inside a cell and 2 more cells inside it as collumns. I still can't think of anyway using colspans and such. 
What i can is totally different approach and may not be suitable to your needs.
Here is a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Anchar/r26cqteb/1/

Comment: @jackhuang Add a class or data attribute to the element that holds the current state. Then the function can check for this and do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I worked it out by pulling out the OpenSlider function and defining each unique slider there.

```
function openSlider(cell) {
  let WhichSlider = cell.id;
  if (WhichSlider === 'cell1') {
    slider1(cell);
  } else if (WhichSlider === 'cell2') {
      slider2(cell);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need two functions `slider1` and `slider2`? Why not just `slider(cell)`?

Comment: If you do need different functions, use `const sliderFuncs = {cell1: slider1, cell2: slider2}; sliderFuncs[cell.id](cell);`

Comment: Oh thanks a lot that's way more convenient.